# jquery opacity cross browser?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, opacity

Is the the `jQuery('#selector').css({'opacity':50});` cross browser?

The only reason i ask is because the line below that we'd normally use on css

`-moz-opacity:.50; filter:alpha(opacity=50); opacity:.50;`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

this is probably better:

```
$(element).fadeTo(0, 0.5);
```

Comment: `css({opacity:50})` does not always work, well on chrome it doesn't, but nice one with `fadeTo` :)

Comment: This is hardly the same, because this not only sets the opacity in a cross browser way, but animates it as well. In the age of CSS3 this may not be desired due to CSS transitions.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik, check the API before making such claims; the first argument here means that there is **no** animation. Also, I'm not sure what the connection is to transitions; none were asked for. In addition, this was clearly posted more than a year ago, and even so, I'm not sure what the age of CSS3 is, considering that some markets are not CSS3 capable.

Comment: First argument is 0 yes, but before claiming this means no animation, you should check jQuery code and see how much code gets executed if `speed` argument is set to 0. But you're right about the age of this question and the non related CSS3 transitions. I take that back.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik, you're right, there is overhead, but that doesn't mean there is animation; they are two separate things. In any case, that amount of code is negligible in terms of CPU time.

Comment: thanks davin, this was a very useful comment! much better than setting opacity via .css()! thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it sets the css opacity or IE's opacity filter.

Answer (score 0):

Because jQuery is designed with cross-browser compatibility in mind, as long as the CSS opacity tag is supported in a browser, then, yes, your jQuery code is cross-browser. (Have you tried it out yet? You can head to [jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) to see if it is.)

For more information, here is the [W3Schools page on opacity](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_transparency.asp). Head there with various browsers and see if it works. (It looks like it works for me in all three major browsers.)

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old post, but I'd just like to add please do not trust or quote W3Schools.  See: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: 100% correct, @daiscog. I was young and dumb. (I block W3School results now.) In fact, it was SO that corrected me for the error of my ways. I are smarter now. ;)