# Change opacity with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help figuring this out! I am trying to change the opacity of a toolbar (Class) that's at the bottom of my site. The following code works for Chrome and Firefox but when it comes to IE8... NO GO. I've tried all kinds of stuff to get this to work but to keep this post clean I'm not gonna list it all.

```
<script>
        function hide() {
             $(".grid_10.bottombar").animate( { opacity: 0, left: 0 }, 1000 );
             $( ".ArrowBottom.float-right" ).show();
        }
  </script>

  <p>
        <img onclick="hide()" src="/images/BlueArrowSmall.png" />
  </p>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out htis SO link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659430/jquery-opacity-cross-browser

Comment: Try adding a `float: left` to the `.grid_10.bottombar` css....

Comment: It works fine. What is the problem? See: http://jsfiddle.net/JaccY/1/ I test in IE8 too

Comment: Thanks for the comment Javad_Amiry. Maybe I have a different underlying problem with my site then? Would you mind taking a look? It's definitely not working with IE8. http://www.computerbytez.com The pic to hide the bar is in the bottom right!

Answer (score 0):

The way i will go with this. Only using jQuery and attach that evenListener to the the class.

```
$(function(){
   $('.bottombar').on('click', function(){
      $(this).animate( { opacity: 0, left: 0 }, 1000, function(){

        $('.ArrowBottom').find('.float-right').show();

      });
   });

});
```