# Hover to show a DIV, mouseleave to hide

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got a DIV, and I would like to show it when mouse is over it, hide it when mouse leaves.

HTML:

```
<div id="test">TESTING</div>
```

CSS:

```
#test {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

JS (assume I use jQuery):

```
$('#test').hover(function() {
  $(this).fadeIn();
});
$('#test').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

But it has no response, and no JS error. I think I missed something stupid. Can anyone give me some lights?

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/EqGve/)

Comment: since the element is hidden... there is no mouseover it

Comment: How do you expect to work mouse events on a hidden element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks all for the input.

Here is the solution I finally have:

After reminded by @Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan, I give up using `display: none`. Instead, I use `opacity`. This makes the CSS a bit complicated, as cross-browser compatibility has to be considered.

Here is the modified CSS (HTML remains unchanged):

```
#test {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* Legacy IE 5-7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"; /* Naughty IE8 */
    -khtml-opacity: 0; /* Safari 1.x */
    -moz-opacity: 0; /* Firefox */
    opacity: 0; /* modern browsers */
    background-color: #F00;
}
```

and here is the modified JS:

```
$('#test').hover(function () {
    $(this).fadeTo(400, 1);
    // $(this).animate({opacity: '1'}, 400);
});
$('#test').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).fadeTo(400, 0);
    // $(this).animate({opacity: '0'}, 400);
});
```

Note that commented-out pair is working too. I was first worried about cross-browser issue, as I use jQuery to change the opacity. However, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659430/jquery-opacity-cross-browser) clears my worries. The function used above is cross-browser.

Last, here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/EqGve/8/) demo.

Answer (score 2):

May be you could do something like this (Show a white space):

HTML:

```
<div id="test" width="100px" height="100px"><span style=font-size:100px;">&#20;</span><div id="child">TESTING</span></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#test').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('#child').fadeIn();
});
$('#test').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).find('#child').fadeOut();
});
```

CSS:

```
 #child {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        display: none;
        background-color: #F00;
    }
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HariprasadKamath/aKAq8/3/)

Comment: Almost, but the mouse over effect only activates on the text only. Since `$('#test')` is attached with `hover()` event, how come not the whole DIV has hover effect ? ( tested on Chrome )

Comment: I have updated my answer as well as the fiddle. Have a look if this is what you meant.

Comment: Almost. DIV is by default occupying full width. I set the DIV to `100px` width. See: http://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/aKAq8/4/

Comment: *sidenote:* HTML attributes have no units ( no `px` ) and font size 100px is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Hover takes 2 functions, the one when hovering in, and one when hovering out. Code :

```
$('#test').hover(function() {
  $(this).fadeIn();
},function() {
  $(this).fadeOut();
} );
```

But.. you cannot hover on something that's not displayed...

Comment: or `$('#test').hover(function() {$(this).fadeToggle()});` but still won't fix OP issue which is a logic issue

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach simply won't work. The element is hidden by default, and therefore can't be found with the mouse on the page.

Delete `display:none;` from your CSS code to make it work, or perhaps set its opacity to lower than 1.0 if you wan't it to be less visible when not hovered over.
In that case you will need to use something like `$('#test').fadeTo(400, 1.0);` to turn its opacity to 1.0 when hovered over.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't hover an hidden element, I whould recommened using opacity with [CSS Transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp), To make it look smooth, you can also try figure something out using z-index that changes on your wanted behaviers.

Hoop ideas will help, Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the command to first show the element since it is hidden.

You can use a button, to first show the element and then hide it or show it!

You code is OK, but the `display: none;` won't let it work. That's why you need to change that or you need to run the code on some other element that is available.

So you code would be like:

```
#test {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

HTML code would be as:

```
<div id="test">TESTING</div>
```

jQuery would be:

```
$(document).ready(function () { // were you missing this too?
  $('#test').hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn();
  });
  $('#test').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
  });
}
```

Comment: Oops, this will affect designer's layout design. The designer wants to hover on a DIV in order to make it show up. (p.s. I set the jQuery code to be executed during onLoad, thus the `$(document).ready` thingy is omitted.